# How to select multiple files in JFileChooser window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jfilechooser

I can't figure out how to select more than one file at a time in the JFileChooser window. I think it is already enabled because I used the `setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)` method on the JFileChooser object, but when I try to actually select more than one, I can't do it. I tried click and drag, CTRL and arrow keys/click, Alt and arrow Keys/click, Shift and arrow keys/click but still no luck. How can I do this?

Code where I create the JFileChooser:
The parse methods are working fine when using only one file.
This class is called when a button is presses in the JFrame.

```
public class FileChooser implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
    private Parser parser = new Parser();
    private static File[] selectedFiles;
    private static File currentSelected;
    private JFileChooser jfc;

    public static File getSelectedFile()
    {
    return currentSelected;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
        new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run()
{
    if ( Window.bFG5IsPressed() && Window.bFGAIsPressed() )
    {
        jfc  = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            selectedFiles = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
            for (File e : selectedFiles) {
                currentSelected = e;
                parser.parseAll(e.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( Window.bFG5IsPressed() )
    {
        jfc  = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            selectedFiles = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
            for (File e : selectedFiles) {
                currentSelected = e;
                parser.parseFG5(e.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

    }
    else if ( Window.bFGAIsPressed() )
    {
        jfc  = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            selectedFiles = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
            for (File e : selectedFiles) {
                currentSelected = e;
                parser.parseFGA(e.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane x = new JOptionPane();
        x.showMessageDialog(x, "Escolher tipo de arquivo");
        x.setLocation(300,300);
        x.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *When* did you use the `setMultiSelectionEnabled`? Show a [mcve] please.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I added the class where I create the JFrame

Comment: @JoeyJohnJo please check the sample in the answer. Please run this whether you are able to select multiple files. If then compare this with your code. If not then let me know.

Comment: You should not be creating a Thread. All Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Listener code does exeute on the EDT. So not only is your code wrong, it is more complex.

Comment: I will take this into account and remove the file chooser from the thread. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call setMultiSelectionEnabled(true). Here is a running sample:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MultipleFileChooser extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleFileChooser multipleFileChooser = new MultipleFileChooser();
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Open Files");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(multipleFileChooser);
                if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File[] openFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
                    System.out.println("Files: " + Arrays.toString(openFiles));
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        multipleFileChooser.add(panel);
        multipleFileChooser.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        multipleFileChooser.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        multipleFileChooser.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Attaching screenshot for OP's reference:
[image]

Comment: @joeyjohnjo please run this whether you are able to select multiple files. If then compare this with your code. If not then let me know.

Comment: I did this but no luck

Comment: Do you mean you ran this sample program and it did not work? What is the OS you are using? Are you able to select multiple files from other applications such as text editors etc.?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me. I assume the setMultiSelectionEnabled is what did for you, so I added to my code aswell, but then it no longer worked. Please see my edit where I added the whole class, thank you

Comment: I see you are creating the file chooser in a different thread. Creating UI in a different thread can be messy. Can you try opening the file chooser directly from `actionPerformed()` method instead of creating a thread and call from `run()` method? I am not sure about your use case but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: So, while I was moving the FileChooser directly into the actionPerformed method, I noticed that I created the file chooser and used setMultiSelectionEnabled only in one of the forks of the if statement, so I added it to all other forks and it worked as intended. I put the JFileChooser in a different thread because the operations performed on the files are quite lengthy and would freeze the whole program while being performed. Thank you very much for your help and the tips on the thread issue

Comment: I would suggest you still not to use a different thread for UI operations. You can do the long-running processing of files in different thread after the files are selected and the file choose is closed.

Comment: Yes, I instantiated the JFileChooser in the actionPerformed() and left only the if statements inside the run. I think this fixes it so that the filechooser itself is not in a different thread, correct?

Comment: Yes, I hope you are calling `showOpenDialog()` also in actionPerformed(). If not you may face other problems. Sounds good :)

Comment: Just moved that line too haha. Thank you so much, you really helped me a lot